# firebase, flutter error 'Could not resolve all files for configuration'

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

today I was learning firebase and I got stuck while running the app.

following is the error that I got when I build the app after changes -:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find auto-value-annotations.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.5/auto-value-annotations-1.6.5.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

below are the file where I made changes and I assume that I did correctly as I am new to firebase and flutter -: App\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flashchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}



dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and below is the android\build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please help me with this...

below is the pubspec.yaml file

```
name: flashchat
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  animated_text_kit: ^2.5.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/flash.png
    - images/flash1.png
```

Comment: Can you show us your pubspec.yml file?

Comment: sure I edited above ...

Comment: hi I have the same problem like yours, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.game_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30 
        multiDexEnabled true  - !!!add this line
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

and also add multiDexEnabled  imlimentation

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add this line
}
```